# PYTHON: plot_confusion_matrix() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'X' and 'y_true

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I created a training model (logistic model) I wanted to plot a confusion matrix but this error appears. What am I missing?

```
## Testing Logistic Model
accuracy_list = []
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
log_reg_pred = reg.predict(x_test)
log_reg_acc = accuracy_score(y_test, log_reg_pred)
accuracy_list.append(100*log_reg_acc)
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, log_reg_pred)
cm

## array([[1360,  191],
         [ 145, 1456]], dtype=int64)


plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})
plt.figure()
plot_confusion_matrix(cm)
plt.title("Logistic Regression Model - Confusion Matrix")
plt.xticks(range(2), ["Existing Customer","Attrited Customer"], fontsize=16)
plt.yticks(range(2), ["Existing Customer","Attrited Customer"], fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 3 plot_confusion_matrix(cm)

**TypeError: plot_confusion_matrix() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'X' and 'y_true'**

Comment: You're importing two different `plot_confusion_matrix` functions...

Comment: You should always put all of your imports at the top of your script. Generally speaking you should also try to stick to importing entire namespaces in cases like this where two or more imported modules have name collisions.